# how to resample data on the dates of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, resampling

Hi I have two dataframes, one is daily and the other monthly (end of month), as below

```
27/1/2020    1
28/1/2020    1.2
29/1/2020    1.2
30/1/2020    1.4
31/1/2020    1.1

31/1/2020    5
28/2/2020    8
31/3/2020    7
```

now, I want to take the first daily dataframe and remove all the dates with the exception of those present in the second dataframe, so the first DF becomes,

```
31/1/2020    1.1
```

In the first dataframe I need to have only the dates and the value based on the dates of the second dataframe. It is a sort of resample base on the dates of another dataframe.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Luigi

Comment: like `df1$date %in% df2$date` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `base R` approach using `%in%`:

```
#Code
df[df$V1 %in% df2$V1,]
```

Output:

```
         V1  V2
5 31/1/2020 1.1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("27/1/2020", "28/1/2020", "29/1/2020", 
"30/1/2020", "31/1/2020"), V2 = c(1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4, 1.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("31/1/2020", "28/2/2020", "31/3/2020"), 
    V2 = c(5L, 8L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```